# Elasticsearch Java api - Partial update of document with bulkProcessor

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-java-api

I am using BulkProcessor of Elasticsearch Java api for insert/update/delete documents in index. 
Following methods works well for inserts and deletes

```
bulkProcessor.add(indexRequest(index).type(type).id(id).source(document))
bulkProcessor.add(deleteRequest(index).type(type).id(id));
```

Could `indexRequest` be used to update partial document in index.
Say in elasticsearch index, I have a document

```
{
  "_id": "abcdefghijk",
  "id": "1",
  "title": "Harry Potter",
  "description": "Description for Harry Potter",
  "price": 10,
  "category": "Book"
}
```

Is it possible to only update price attribute in the document, say I want to change price to `{"price":15}` using `indexRequest` or with any other methods in api

Answer (score 1):

The following code shall solve the problem.

```
   final BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequest = esClient.prepareBulk();

   //start loop for multiple products

   final XContentBuilder contentBuilder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder();
    try {

      contentBuilder.startObject();
      contentBuilder.field("price", 20);
      contentBuilder.endObject();

    } catch (final IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  bulkRequest.add(esClient.prepareUpdate(index, type,_id).setDetectNoop(false)
          .setDoc(contentBuilder));
    //end loop

    BulkResponse bulkResponse = bulkRequest.execute().actionGet();
```

Comment: This is bulkRequest but I think its not possible with bulkProcessor using indexRequest

Answer (score 1):

```
bulkProcessor.add(new UpdateRequest(indexName, type, docId).doc(document).upsert(document));
```

If the document id does not exist, the content of the upsert element will be used to index a new document, else if already exist, the content of doc element used to update document.